# Wamp Virtual Host cause problem to routing path

Tags: symfony, path, routes

First of all, my code works perfectly fine and doesn't have any relation with the problem  so dont waste time reading it and checking it, i"ll include it anyway!

I am using a wamp virtual host :

> Virtual Host  : Stage
>      Path  : C:\wamp\www\Dhia\public

when I test using the virtual host (http://stageapp/) the index page works fine, but the contact doesn't work

when I go to http://stageapp/contact (it shows 404 not found)

but when I run the server with >php bin/console server:run
 and I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact it works fine !

So using the virtual host is causing this problem!

What is the correct virtual host path I should use instead of `"C:\wamp\www\Dhia\public"` ?

I am using Symfony 4.4.2 !
here is the code of DhiaController.php :

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

    class DhiaController  {

        public function indexAction() 
        {
            return new Response('<html><body>Hello worldbbb</body></html>');    
        }

        public function contactAction()
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>contact...</body></html>');
    }

    }
```

Here is the code of routes.yaml :

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\DhiaController::indexAction

contact:
    path: /contact
    controller: App\Controller\DhiaController::contactAction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install apache pack and then try:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

See this doc:

> https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html